# What's the minimum set of tools I need to open Windows Azure samples shipped by Microsoft?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, azure, cloud

I wanted to try open "Hello World" from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg432966.aspx). I already had Visual Studio 2010 installed. I went [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7a1089b6-4050-4307-86c4-9dadaa5ed018) and downloaded `WindowsAzureSDK-x86.exe` and installed the SDK.

Yet when I double click the .sln in the sample Visual Studio opens the .csproj (the project with web role) just fine but complains it can't open the .ccproj file because *its project type is not supported by this version of the application*.

What else do I have to install so that I can open that .ccproj project file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to also install the thing called "VSCloudService.exe" on the [same page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7a1089b6-4050-4307-86c4-9dadaa5ed018). Once I installed it .ccproj files open just fine.

Answer (score 9):

You need the Windows Azure SDK+tools. The easiest way to do this is to visit [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/getstarted/) and select "Get Tools and SDK." This will fire up the Web Platform Installer, which should do a much better job of setting up your environment.

A few more things: You'll need SQL Express (or SQL Server) installed as well. I "think" the Web Platform Installer will take care of that for you, but I'm not 100% sure. Also, you'll need to run Visual Studio as Administrator, to allow it to properly interact with the local Windows Azure simulator.